# How to pop up a message box when user clicks anywhere within the form window in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, messagebox

I'm fairly new to Visual Studio in C#.

I was wondering how to pop up a message box when the user clicks anywhere within the form window.

Basically, I don't want them accessing and interacting with the program unless they have a password.

Code for the `Form1()` is really simple right now:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

The actual interface has a bunch of buttons and settings (buttons and settings I don't want the user to be able to interact with unless they have verified themselves).

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding the 1st questions. 
You usually create a second model form , that is transparent and is on top of your form. 
Handle the on-click event of the transparent form .

Regarding the second questions- you should rethink your design , maybe do not show the sensitive form at all untill a user has typed the password.

By the way , you have not specified what tech do you use? 
is it desktop (winforms / wpf , other)/ web (web forms, asp mvc, other) ?

recommended reading for client side windows programming.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492132.aspx

Edit:
In order to put a form on top of another form , you use a model dialog.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39wcs2dh(v=vs.110).aspx

In order to create a form transparent

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czke9azk(v=vs.110).aspx

Also , it still depends on your UI technology.

Provided links are form winforms, other technology may require a different approach.

Edit: 
As another answer pointed out , you could also bind to the original forms click event , but you will also have to bind to every child control click event recursively.

Comment: Hmm, I see. How can I go about putting the Form2() on top of the main form? I currently have made the second form the same size as Form1. Not sure of the next steps... I currently have this: `static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form2());
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }`

Answer (score 1):

Click on form and press `F4` key that show  property window then click on event button there you click on click event that show in .cs file of form .

Make function like

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Click");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! Learned a few things with this post. Anyways, this only executes when I click on the actual form, anything inside the form that I click on won't pop up that message...